# jQuery keyup/onchange bug

Tags: jquery, onchange, keyup, large-data

A user can insert order values via a large number (>500) of input fields on a page:

```
<input type="text" name="%id%" data-product_id="%id%" class="updateQtyField" maxlength="4">
```

It isn't possible to use a 'save' button so we make use of a jQuery script for updating the insert data to a session:

```
  $("input.updateQtyField").keyup(function() {
    $.post("update.php", { product_id: $(this).data('product_id'), qty: $(this).val() }, function(result) { if (result != 1) { alert(result); } });
  });
```

Unfortunately, there is a possibility that the $.post request didn't update the field and I have absolutely no idea why. Probably because the users of the system are working very quick: insert value - tab - insert value - tab - etc. Via a log i've seen that the `keyup` trigger works well, but the `$.post` doesn't do his job. It looks like there isn't any respons from the post job.

I've tried to use a workaround via an extra `onChange` action, but also this isn't preforming very well, again not all the fields are updated correctly. Another option I've tried is working well but give some performing issues: send on every `keyup` alle the input fields. The result is very good, but the page freeze for a few seconds and ins't a good solution.

The PHP file update.php is a very simple file:
`$_SESSION['productQty'][$_POST['product_id']] = $_POST['qty'];`

Comment: Can't you use blur event? It should be ideal as when you move out of input box then it posts the value of that input box. This was you can save multiple requests firing.

Comment: That is an option but will slow down the system! There should be a real solution ;-)

Comment: Is there such specific requirement that you need separate post requests for every input field. Can't you modify the PHP logic and send one request in which data sent will be array of all fields data??

Comment: That is a possibility, but there isn't a possibility to make use of a 'save' button. So, it should be a background task and the disadvantage of a request with all the input fields is a page freeze because of the large number of input fields.

Comment: Don't think there's any other event when you can trigger such post if you are not using save button.  Blur will save you freeze issue as it will send one request per field as compared to keyup while you move for next field.
If you need requests sent with individual values of fields this looks like only way. Hope someone have better alternative than this.